# Does $x_k$ identically distributed with finite mean imply $x_k/k$ converges to 0 $a.s.$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am not sure whether the following statement is true. Let $x_k$ be identically distributed, and only assumed to have finite mean. Can we conclude that $x_k/k$ converges a.s.? Clearly it converges in probability. And if we compute
$$
 P(|x_k|\geq k\epsilon)\leq \frac{E|x_k|}{k\epsilon}$$

However, since we only assume finite mean, it is not sufficient to conclude the almost everywhere convergence. I can come up with counterexamples when $x_i$ are not identically distributed. But not for the identically distributed case. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true. I will use $X_k$ instead of $x_k$. To show $X_k/k\to 0$ a.s, it suffices to show $\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(|X_k/k|>\epsilon)<\infty$, for all $\epsilon>0$.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(|X_k/k|>\epsilon)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(|X_1/\epsilon|>k)\le \int_0^\infty P(|X_1/\epsilon|>t)\,dt=E|X_1/\epsilon|
<\infty$$
In fact, you can prove the converse, that $X_k/k\to 0$ a.s. implies $E|X_1|<\infty$, in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I think not.

Let $X_i \sim Poisson(\lambda)$.

Then $P(X_k \le k) =\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}e^{-\lambda}$.

For every $n$, we will have that $P(X_n \le n, X_{n+1}\le n+1, ...) = P(X_n \le n) P(X_{n+1} \le n+1) \cdots < P(X_n \le n) < 1$.

Hence the limit of $X_i / i$ is not probabilistically guaranteed to stay below $1$ for big enough $n$, so $P(\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{X_n}{n} = 0) < 1$

Comment: But Poisson has finite second moment, by the inequality $P(|x_k|\geq k\epsilon)\leq \frac{E|x_k|^2}{k^2\epsilon^2}$. Then we have $P(|x_k|\geq n\epsilon\, i.o)=0$ by Borel-Cantelli Lemma, which is equivalent to $x_k/k$ converges to 0 a.s.

Comment: @Zorualyh that shows that some elements of any sequence will almost surely be close to $0$. But you can flip that reasoning around to show that any sequence will almost surely have infinite elements $X_n \ge n$

Comment: This answer is wrong. For any fixed $n$, we will have a positive probability that \textit{some} $X_n$ will be greater than $n$. But that doesn't certainly mean that, when we intersect those events we will obtain an event with positive probability. I.e. the evente that \textit{for all} $n$ we will obtain a $k \ge n$ with $X_k \ge k$ will have not positive probability.

Comment: Ah, damn yes you are right